# Default start value for picker

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I want to have blank value in my picker when I start the app(before I make selection).

Currently when I launch my app picker shows Value1 in the box. Here is my List that I bind with Picker:

`private List<string> _PickerValueBind = new List<string>() {"Value1", "Value2"};`

And the xaml:

```
<Picker  ItemsSource="{Binding PickerValueBind}"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" IsEnabled="{Binding PickerEnabledBind}" SelectedIndex="{Binding PickerIndexBind}">
      <Picker.Behaviors>
           <prism:EventToCommandBehavior
                  EventName="SelectedIndexChanged"
                  Command="{Binding IndexChangedBind}" />
      </Picker.Behaviors>
</Picker>
```

I tried using Picker.Title but it didn't work as desired. Also tried adding empty item as first item but in the end I don't want user to have option to pick empty value.

Answer (score 0):

Set value of `PickerIndexBind = -1` in viewmodel

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53204920/unable-to-set-default-value-for-picker-in-xamarin-forms